# Input tag without form

Tags: html, ajax

I am trying to analyze the following html code, in full source code I cannot find form tag.
When user clicks Buy link user completes the commerce order so how I can find which url is submitted with the following code snippet?

```
<input type="hidden" name="promo-code-id" value="167">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button-cta with-fullsize cStart   disabled" style="display: yes;" data-id="167">Buy</a>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the live site or a full example? Nothing in the snippet shows how the information is being handled.

Comment: here is the web page http://beklediginizedegecek.turkcell.com.tr/ all html codes reside

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Comment: @mmc18 where on that page is the code you mention? I followed the link and can not find a single input tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Developer Tools from the browser ( like Firebug) they all have a network monitoring panel where you can see the actual requests initiated and to on what URL

Comment: I know this tool, but I want to analyze code in offline mode not online

Comment: So the developer tools will show you the URL and tell you that the DNS lookup failed. What's the problem?